# Тире в простом предложении (2)

Tags: пунктуация, тире, интонация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли в этом предложении тире (сказуемое выражено глаголом, а подлежащее — существительными)?

**Динозавры, мамонты — приходят и уходят. А муравьи и тараканы остаются.**

На работе спорим. Половина говорит, что тире не нужно, а другая настаивает на том, что тут интонационная пауза.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение  не очень удачно составлено.  Оба варианта, с интонационным тире и без тире, правилами не запрещены, но для произношения неудобны.

Вариант редактирования:

*ДинозАвры, мАмонты — **они** приходят и ухОдят. А муравьи и таракАны //остаЮтся.*

Тире — это не только письменный знак и не только пауза в речи. Тире влияет на расстановку логических ударений, на **выделение** тех слов, которые вы хотите подчеркнуть в предложении.

Answer (score 1):

В этих двух предложениях я бы расставила акценты совсем по-другому.
Смысл сообщения, думаю, таков: **крупные** животные (ящеры, птеродактили и многочисленные "завры") периодически появляются на планете и с такой же периодичностью **исчезают**, а вот всякая "мелочь" — нет, не исчезает (насекомые появились более 400 млн лет назад и живут до сих пор).

Я написала бы так:
**Динозавры и мамонты приходят и уходят. А муравьи и тараканы — остаются.**
(Можно даже восклицательный знак в конце поставить.)

Тире ставится для указания места разделения простого предложения на словесные группы, чтобы подчеркнуть либо уточнить смысловые отношения между членами предложения, когда другими знаками препинания или порядком слов нужный смысл не может быть выражен.
Сравните:
***Ходить — долго не мог*** (лишен был возможности передвигаться в течение длительного периода, например после тяжелой болезни); ***Ходить долго — не мог*** (не мог заниматься длительной ходьбой).

[Интонационное тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94) (Розенталь)

P. S. Точка ставится **после** закрывающих кавычек. («А муравьи и тараканы остаются».)
[Кавычки и другие знаки](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=178)

Comment: Римма, мне всё нравится в вашем предложении, но есть одно замечание. Вторая часть должна читаться с определенным ударением, а оно неочевидно: А муравьИ и тараканы — остаются. Если ударение перенести на второе слово, то тире сложно обозначить паузой.

Comment: Вообще-то я бы оформила это предложение совсем иначе. **Динозавры и мамонты приходят и уходят — муравьи и тараканы остаются.** Но это уже не будет _простым_ предложением. Можно, конечно, и добавить в ответ. Стоит ли? Вопрос ведь о другой конструкции.

Comment: А еще лучше: "Динозавры и мамонты приходят и уходят, а муравьи и тараканы остаются". Просто и понятно. И никаких тире.

Comment: Ну да, для самого закрученного вопроса практически всегда можно подобрать наипростейший вариант.